# Query in ContentValues

Tags: android, performance, sqlite, cursor, content-values

I have to insert a lot of rows in my **SQLite Database** and for some tables
a specific value of each row has to be converted into an other using the value of an other table.
Actually, I have this function which is working well:

```
public void myFunction( String tableName, String attrName, ContentValues currentVal ) { 

    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT colName FROM "+tableName+" WHERE "+tableName+".otherColName = " + currentVal.getAsString(attrName), null);

    Long realValue = null;
    if( c.moveToFirst() ) { 
        realValue = c.getLong(0);
    }
    if( c != null ) c.close();

    currentVal.put( attrName, realValue );

}
```

But, this is really time consumimg because of this part:

```
if( c.moveToFirst() ) { 
    realValue = c.getLong(0);
}
```

So I wanted to know if there's a way to set the query directly in the value of the ContantValue like this:

```
currentVal.put( attrName, "SELECT colName FROM "+tableName+" WHERE "+tableName+".otherColName = " + currentVal.getAsString(attrName));
```

and the query will be executed at the same time as the insert query in order to replace the value.

**Thank you beforehand!**

Comment: Please, some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No, `ContentValues` is just a wrapper of a hash map for the data. You can try to use index to accelerate the query.

Comment: I already use indexes. But if you know an other way to solve my problem ... The problem is in the `c.moveToFirst()` which is really time consuming even if I use indexes, foreign keys ...

Comment: @NicolasCortell How many rows do you have, and how long does it take to do the query?

Comment: For the largest table I have more than 1 000 000 rows. Sometimes, I have to insert 10 000 to 20 000 rows at once and for each rows I have to replace the specific value before inserting the row. It can take about 20 minutes to achieve the insert of the 20 000 rows.

Comment: @NicolasCortell Have you used transactions for the operation? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction()

Comment: Yes, I already did but it still taking too much time. Maybe I should write my own `Cursor` class. Really don't know.